# Are there assets to collect in EVERY star system?

Tags: mass-effect-3

The percentage meter of completion doesn't show until you found an asset in the Star System. So no way to know which have or not.

So do all have some assets to collect, or some don't?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, there are quite a few systems that have nothing to be found in them.

The most obvious example is the system with the Citadel in it.

There's a [Scanning Guide](http://www.computerandvideogames.com/339171/mass-effect-3-complete-scanning-guide-and-how-to-get-the-best-possible-ending/) that is usually linked whenever we start talking about system scanning, but I'm not 100% convinced it is true and complete.  It's certainly correct about a few of the systems though, such as the Horsehead Nebula, which contains nothing scannable.

Comment: As a side note, any system that you scan where "0%" doesn't show up under the name of the system doesn't have any assets (at least at the time of the scan, maybe later as well) for you to retrieve.